# MongoDB one query with multiple OR or multiple queries?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Every user has a mobile number, and I want to check there are other users in my address book.

So I have 1000 numbers and I want to check if any of the is in the database, so my initial idea is that for each number I run a mongodb query:

```
for (var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  db.users.findOne({phoneNumber: numbers[i]});
}
```

however I have been suggested to do so:

```
db.users.find($or: numbers.map(function(number){return {phoneNumber: number}}));
// That would result into a
// db.users.find($or:[{phoneNumber: "123"}, {phoneNumber: "234"}...])
```

Now are the two equivalent? Is the second way more expensive?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) would be the cleanest way to find the docs where `phoneNumber` appears in `numbers`:

```
db.users.find({phoneNumber: {$in: numbers}})
```

Comment: apparently if `numbers.length == 500` it takes at least 30s

Comment: @haskellguy is that your own results or just heresay? At any rate $in will be more efficient than $or as the latter is exclusive. The main performance factor will be how many numbers you have in the array of the documents in the collection,

Comment: what kind of complexity does $in has? assuming I have `n` documents and `m` elements in the array?